# Facebook Graph Api Get tagged comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to gather information about the number of comments from a facebook past that include a tag to a user, i.e. when you type @Joe Bloggs.

I know you can get all comments by either getting using the Comments edge for a post `v2.8/[Postid]/comments` or by the comment id directly `v2.8/[comment-id]`

But the message field that is returned is plain text and includes no indication of tags. e.g. something like:

```
{
  "created_time": "2017-02-28T09:31:08+0000",
  "from": {
    "name": "Fred Bloggs",
    "id": "123"
  },
  "message": "Joe Bloggs look at this",
  "id": "1234"
}
```

Is it possible to get this somehow?

Comment: `message_tags` field, same as for normal posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the field `message_tags` in your request. It will give you an array of profiles tagged in this comment.

Comment: I used this with "[post-id]?fields=comments{message_tags}" Thanks!